# In a spreadsheet bound GAS script using HtmlService how can I include Stylesheet (CSS) and JavaScript content?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can only get CSS and JavaScript content to be served if I place it all on the main page rather than in separate files like the [Best Practices documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript) advocates. This makes the main page very long and a right mess to read & navigate.

Rather than force you to makes sense of my own script, I've created two spreadsheets, shared with anyone who has the links below, with scripts copied from the documentation to illustrate the problem. In each, to run the script, click on Dialog in the menu bar then Open. To view the scripts, you know the drill, click Tools then Script Editor.

[Demo 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqhxB2z2m3HsdFg1NUtCemlVUHJPUmRMazJsLVFhYXc&usp=sharing) shows that CSS & JavaScript placed on the main html page works.

[Demo 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqhxB2z2m3HsdFBaVDhDMlhSTDFtRkVnWFJoU0ZpV1E&usp=sharing) shows that CSS & JavaScript placed in separate files doesn't work.

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
      .setTitle('My custom dialog')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.show(html);
}
```

to:

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
      .setTitle('My custom dialog')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.show(html);
}
```

and it works.

Comment: Thank you pete. I despair sometimes! The documentation even stipulates .createTemplateFromFile('Page') but I didn't spot my mistake.